# Storing all values of a changing variable in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a variable called **CurrentLineup**, which contains a set of 5 names as such

```
set(['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3', 'Player 4', 'Player 5'])
```

I have a loop of all of the events during a game, which includes other players' substitutions in and out of the game.

What I would like to do is create a list of all 5 man sets as **CurrentLineup** updates, so I initialized the following outside of the loop... take this code as an example.

```
Lineup_List = []
Lineup_List.append(Current_Lineup)

For i in game_events:
    if "Enters Game" in i:
        player = 'Player 6'
        Current_Lineup.add(player)
    if "Leaves Game" in i:
        player2 = 'Player 4'
        Current_Lineup.remove(player2)
    if len(Current_Lineup) == 5:
        Lineup_List.append(Current_Lineup)
```

My problem is that when I return Lineup_List after the loop, it has the final version of Current_Lineup a number of times.

If this loop ran twice, I would hope for Lineup_List to have the following result:

```
[set(['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3', 'Player 4', 'Player 5']), 
 set(['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3', 'Player 6', 'Player 5'])]
```

How do I retain the various values that CurrentLineup takes through the loop, in order of occurrence?

Comment: the list stores a reference to the very same set multiple times. you can `append(copy.deepcopy(myset))` to store a copy, not the original

Comment: It is probably not needed (or even desirable) to perform a deep copy. A shallow copy should be what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a (shallow) copy of the set when you append it, otherwise you just keep changing the same set, also when already referenced in the line up list. So change the last line as follows (add `set()`):

```
Lineup_List.append(set(Current_Lineup))
```

This appends a *copy* of your current line up set, so that you can safely change it in the next iterations without affecting the already added set(s).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @trincot. I get the following error with your suggestion: TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where you said it was a set. I understood it to be a list. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth... but here's the newest error with your updated answer. "NameError: global name 'Current_Lineup' is not defined"

Comment: Your question does not have the code for the initial assignment to `Current_Lineup`, and you have `For` written with a capital, which is invalid syntax. But besides that, it works: https://repl.it/FaiY

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for your help.